# Meta Box doesn't appear

Tags: custom-post-types

I have 3 custom post types and 3 meta box files. The problem is I include files in `functions.php`. I have three meta box PHP files for each custom post type, but it just shows one meta box fields of custom post which is recently added. Example:

functions.php :

```
include 'inc/referanslar.php';
include 'inc/hizmetler/hizmetler.php';
include 'inc/projeler.php',
include 'inc/projeler-meta-box.php',
include 'inc/hizmetler/hizmetler-meta-box.php';
include 'inc/referanslar-meta-box.php';
```

It just shows `referanslar-meta-box.php` because it's under all files. Here are my meta box files:

[hizmetler-meta-box.php](http://codepad.org/MZwPFu4K) :

```
/*
* Plugin Name: Hizmetler Özel Alanlar
* Author: Erdinç Taze
* Author URI: http://erdinctaze.com/
*/
$prefix = 'ozellikler_'; 
$meta_box = array(
'id' => 'my-meta-box',
'title' => 'Hizmet Özellikleri',
'page' => 'hizmetler',
'context' => 'normal',
'priority' => 'high',
'fields' => array(
array(

'name' => 'Hizmet İkon',
'desc' => 'Lütfen hizmet ikonunuzu seçiniz',
'id' => $prefix . 'hizmetikon',
'type' => 'select',
'options' => array('web-design', 'google-apps', 'graphic-design', 'web-development', 'seo', 'mobile-app', 'social-media-promotion', 'online-promotion', 'web-application', 'orm')
),
array(
'name' => 'Hizmet Bağlantı Adresi',
'desc' => 'Lütfen devamını oku butonuna tıklandığında gidilecek bağlantıyı giriniz.',
'id' => $prefix . 'hizmeturl',
'type' => 'text',
),

)
); 
add_action('admin_menu', 'mytheme_add_box'); 
// Add meta box
function mytheme_add_box() {
global $meta_box; 
add_meta_box($meta_box['id'], $meta_box['title'], 'mytheme_show_box', $meta_box['page'], $meta_box['context'], $meta_box['priority']);
} 
// Callback function to show fields in meta box
function mytheme_show_box() {
global $meta_box, $post; 
// Use nonce for verification
echo '<input type="hidden" name="mytheme_meta_box_nonce" value="', wp_create_nonce(basename(__FILE__)), '" />'; 
echo '<table class="form-table">'; 
foreach ($meta_box['fields'] as $field) {
// get current post meta data
$meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field['id'], true); 
echo '<tr>',
'<th style="width:20%"><label for="', $field['id'], '">', $field['name'], '</label></th>',
'<td>';
switch ($field['type']) {
case 'text':
echo '<input type="text" name="', $field['id'], '" id="', $field['id'], '" value="', $meta ? $meta : $field['std'], '" size="30" style="width:97%" />',
'<br />', $field['desc'];
break;
case 'textarea':
echo '<textarea name="', $field['id'], '" id="', $field['id'], '" cols="60" rows="4" style="width:97%">', $meta ? $meta : $field['std'], '</textarea>',
'<br />', $field['desc'];
break;
case 'select':
echo '<select name="', $field['id'], '" id="', $field['id'], '">';
foreach ($field['options'] as $option) {
echo '<option', $meta == $option ? ' selected="selected"' : '', '>', $option, '</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
break;
case 'radio':
foreach ($field['options'] as $option) {
echo '<input type="radio" name="', $field['id'], '" value="', $option['value'], '"', $meta == $option['value'] ? ' checked="checked"' : '', ' />', $option['name'];
}
break;
case 'checkbox':
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="', $field['id'], '" id="', $field['id'], '"', $meta ? ' checked="checked"' : '', ' />';
break;
}
echo '<td>',
'</tr>';
} 
echo '</table>';
} 
add_action('save_post', 'mytheme_save_data'); 
// Save data from meta box
function mytheme_save_data($post_id) {
global $meta_box; 
// verify nonce
if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['mytheme_meta_box_nonce'], basename(__FILE__))) {
return $post_id;
} 
// check autosave
if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
return $post_id;
} 
// check permissions
if ('page' == $_POST['post_type']) {
if (!current_user_can('edit_page', $post_id)) {
return $post_id;
}
} elseif (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {
return $post_id;
} 
foreach ($meta_box['fields'] as $field) {
$old = get_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], true);
$new = $_POST[$field['id']]; 
if ($new && $new != $old) {
update_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $new);
} elseif ('' == $new && $old) {
delete_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $old);
}
}
}
```

[referanslar-meta-box.php](http://codepad.org/lDnoC71J) :

```
/*
* Plugin Name: Referanslar Özel Alanlar
* Author: Erdinç Taze
* Author URI: http://erdinctaze.com/
*/
$prefix = 'erdinc_'; 
$meta_box = array(
'id' => 'referans_meta_box',
'title' => 'Referans Ayrıntılar',
'page' => 'logolar',
'callback' => 'show_custom_meta_box',
'context' => 'normal',
'priority' => 'high',
'fields' => array(
array(
'name' => 'Yapılan İşlemler',
'desc' => 'Lütfen firma için yapılan hizmetleri belirtiniz.',
'id' => $prefix . 'islemler',
'type' => 'text',
),
array(
'name' => 'Referans URL',
'desc' => 'Lütfen referans butonuna tıklandığında gidilecek bağlantıyı giriniz.',
'id' => $prefix . 'referansurl',
'type' => 'text',
),
)
); 
add_action('admin_menu', 'mytheme_add_box'); 
// Add meta box
function referans_add_box() {
global $meta_box; 
add_meta_box($meta_box['id'], $meta_box['title'], 'mytheme_show_box', $metabox['callback'], $meta_box['page'], $meta_box['context'], $meta_box['priority']);
} 
// Callback function to show fields in meta box
function referans_show_box() {
global $meta_box, $post; 
// Use nonce for verification
echo '<input type="hidden" name="mytheme_meta_box_nonce" value="', wp_create_nonce(basename(__FILE__)), '" />'; 
echo '<table class="form-table">'; 
foreach ($meta_box['fields'] as $field) {
// get current post meta data
$meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field['id'], true); 
echo '<tr>',
'<th style="width:20%"><label for="', $field['id'], '">', $field['name'], '</label></th>',
'<td>';
switch ($field['type']) {
case 'text':
echo '<input type="text" name="', $field['id'], '" id="', $field['id'], '" value="', $meta ? $meta : $field['std'], '" size="30" style="width:97%" />',
'<br />', $field['desc'];
break;
case 'textarea':
echo '<textarea name="', $field['id'], '" id="', $field['id'], '" cols="60" rows="4" style="width:97%">', $meta ? $meta : $field['std'], '</textarea>',
'<br />', $field['desc'];
break;
case 'select':
echo '<select name="', $field['id'], '" id="', $field['id'], '">';
foreach ($field['options'] as $option) {
echo '<option', $meta == $option ? ' selected="selected"' : '', '>', $option, '</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
break;
case 'radio':
foreach ($field['options'] as $option) {
echo '<input type="radio" name="', $field['id'], '" value="', $option['value'], '"', $meta == $option['value'] ? ' checked="checked"' : '', ' />', $option['name'];
}
break;
case 'checkbox':
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="', $field['id'], '" id="', $field['id'], '"', $meta ? ' checked="checked"' : '', ' />';
break;
}
echo '<td>',
'</tr>';
} 
echo '</table>';
} 
add_action('save_post', 'mytheme_save_data'); 
// Save data from meta box
function referans_save_data($post_id) {
global $meta_box; 
// verify nonce
if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['mytheme_meta_box_nonce'], basename(__FILE__))) {
return $post_id;
} 
// check autosave
if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
return $post_id;
} 
// check permissions
if ('page' == $_POST['post_type']) {
if (!current_user_can('edit_page', $post_id)) {
return $post_id;
}
} elseif (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {
return $post_id;
} 
foreach ($meta_box['fields'] as $field) {
$old = get_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], true);
$new = $_POST[$field['id']]; 
if ($new && $new != $old) {
update_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $new);
} elseif ('' == $new && $old) {
delete_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $old);
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without adding your custom post type, it looks like you've got the function called wrong on the second one

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'mytheme_add_box'); 
// Add meta box
function referans_add_box() {
```

Do you want to say

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'referans_add_box'); 
// Add meta box
function referans_add_box() {
```

Comment: I edited as u said but the problem still occurs.

Comment: Check the second hook -> add_action('save_post', 'mytheme_save_data');

Comment: I recently edited this line also. But didnt help

Comment: If you comment out the first meta box file from the functions.php does the second one work then?

Comment: Yeap,  for instance; if i put referanslar-meta-box.php last line on functions.php it works and the others doesnt work. But if i put hizmetler-meta-box.php last line it works then and others doesnt work.

Comment: Can you update the referanslar-meta-box.php to the latest version, and show your create the custom post type as well? (referanslar.php)